# jquery ui slider value with dot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the output of my slider seperate thousands with dot

```
$(function() {
    var s = $( "#sliderRange" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 200000,
        min: 0,
        max: 600000,
        step: 5000,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val(  ui.value + "kr" );

        }
    });

    $('#up').click(function() {
        s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider( "option", "step" ) );   
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#sliderRange" ).slider( "value" ) + "kr"  );
    });

    $('#down').click(function() {
        s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider( "option", "step" ) );   
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#sliderRange" ).slider( "value" ) + "kr"  );
    });


});
```

Now output is e.g. 300000kr but I want output like this 300.000kr

Comment: do you want to use the dot(.) as thousand separator?

Comment: Yes I want the output like 300.000kr

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you I find the solution with plugin http://jquerypriceformat.com/

Answer (score 0):

I hope his one will be the easiest solution for you. Create a function which insert the dots

```
function numberWithDots(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```

And change one of your jQuery codes like this

```
$( "#amount" ).val(  numberWithDots(ui.value) + "kr" );
```